# How to get the fillColor of a sublayer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I have created a number of circles inside individual UIViews.
The circles are made with a CAShapeLayer and has different colors.

Each UIView is saved in an array.

When I pick a random index in the array, I want to "measure" the color of the cirkle with that index.

I have tried to access the sublayer of the UIView and then get its "background color".
But I get a nill value.

```
func createBalls(addToView circleView: UIView, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, size: CGFloat, color: CGColor) -> UIView {
    //create view to contain circle
    let containerView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .clear
            return view
    }()
    // add container view to view
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: x + size/2, y: y + size/2, width: size, height: size)
    circleView.addSubview(containerView)
    //create circle inside container view
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: containerView.bounds)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    containerView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    circleView.clipsToBounds = false
    return containerView
}

func sampleOfCircles(addToView circleView: UIView, circleSize: CGFloat) {
    nBalls = Int.random(in: 3...5)
    nRedBalls = Int.random(in: 1...nBalls - 1)
    nBlueBalls = nBalls - nRedBalls
    for i in 0...nBalls-1 {
        let x = CGFloat(10 + i*(Int(circleSize) + 5))
        let y = circleView.frame.height/2
        if i < nRedBalls {
            ballArray.append(createBalls(addToView: circleView, x: x, y: y, size: circleSize, color: UIColor.red.cgColor))
        } else {
            ballArray.append(createBalls(addToView: circleView, x: x, y: y, size: circleSize, color: UIColor.blue.cgColor))
        }
    }
}

func createBallProblem(viewStackLeft: UIView, viewStackRight: UIView, viewBottom: UIView) {
   sampleOfCircles(addToView: viewStackLeft, circleSize: K.Ball.ballWidth)
   for a in ballArray {
      let color = a.layer.sublayers?.last?.backgroundColor
      print(color)
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting color to layer using *fillColor*, not *backgroundColor*. That's why you are receiving *nil*.

To retrieve color you've set use this code:

```
let color = (a.layer.sublayers?.last as? CAShapeLayer)?.fillColor
print(color)
```